# Has Stack Exchange changed how it counts daily visits?

Tags: discussion

I realize that this is almost certainly a network-wide question, but I am asking it here, because this is the only site on which I have seen it manifest:

Has there been a change in how daily visits are calculated?  (I noticed this in the context of the Fanatic badge on the physics meta site.)  I have probably visited every day for the past hundred, during my normal working hours; however, up until this time, daily visits seemed to be counted only according to UCT.  Has this changed?

I noticed this because my Fanatic badge progress was somewhere in the 30s out of 100 yesterday, but then it jumped to me having the badge (with no notification).

**Update:**  Things now appear to have gone back to what they were before (I no longer have the Fanatic badge of physics meta), so this may have just been a temporary glitch, perhaps never to be explained.

Comment: Related on Meta SE: [What is an SE “day”? When does each day start?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/27199/241919) and [Fanatic badge days count reset to zero , account's “visited x days” shows 59 Days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315081/241919). In general, "visiting" is not enough, and some "activities" are needed to be recorded.

Comment: @AndrewT.  See my edit.

Comment: Did you mean the Fanatic badge progress indicator is now 100 or shows if you got the badge? (A screenshot would help ;) Because [you don't seem to have the Fanatic badge on Meta Physics](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/users/70245/buzz?tab=badges) nor [Fanatic badge on any sites network-wide recently](https://stackexchange.com/users/5590647/buzz?tab=activity).

Comment: You earned the Fanatic badge on Physics [back in 2016](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/badges/23/fanatic?userid=70245), but you [don't have it on Meta](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/23/fanatic?userid=70245).  You're currently at 38 consecutive days on Physics and Physics Meta (you took March 17 off).  A screenshot would help us to interpret what you are seeing.

Comment: @rob It was the Fanatic badge on Meta.  I was at 37 consecutive days; then I had the badge; then I was back at 38 consecutive days, and the gold badge disappeared from my top bar.

Comment: I think the answer is probably yes. Some years ago you had need to create some entity, for the software recognize it as a visit. Although even a vote entity was enough. As I can see, now it is enough if you make a page load.